# Finding all solutions of $2\sin(c_1\omega)+\sin(c_2\omega)=0$ for $\omega$, when $c_1$ and $c_2$ are given positive real numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form

I try to solve the following problem, which consists of 1 equation and 1 unknown.
\begin{align}
2\sin(c_1\omega)+\sin(c_2\omega)=0
\end{align}
Suppose $c_1$ and $c_2$ are known positive real numbers. $\omega$ is the variable which needs to be solved for. $\omega=0$ is one solution but is there a way to get a couple more solutions in the positive direction? I tried to bring it in a polynomial form. Let $\omega = \cos^{-1}(z)$, then:
\begin{align}
2\sin(c_1\cos^{-1}(z))+\sin(c_2\cos^{-1}(z))=0
\end{align}
If $c_1$ and $c_2$ would be just integers I could simplify it much easier but this is not the case. Is there anyway to rewrite this in a different way, and maybe extract $\omega$? Any help or hint is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want all solutions? Because $\omega = 0$ clearly works. But I am rather sure that there is no nice way to write them down.

Comment: Yes, all solution, even just a few more than $\omega=0$ would be nice. (I will make an edit to the question). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Rewriting sin(x) into exponential form as mentioned [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-an-expression-for-sin-x-in-terms-of-e-ix-and-e-ix) might help you, but it might also be a dead end, I'm not sure.

Comment: *«Abandon hope all ye who enter here »* wrote Dante in the *Divine Comedy*

Answer (score -1):

COMMENT.- $(1)$ Plotting the function $f(\omega)=2\sin(c_1\omega)+\sin(c_2\omega)$ with $c_1,c_2$ positive real, one can see the graphic can be very complicated. However it seems $f(\omega)$ is always periodic. It follows that if you can find out the period in each case your are done because $f(0)=0$.

Unfortunately the determination of these periods are not at all easy. For example for $(c_1,c_2)=(1.3,3.7)$ Wolfram gives the period $20\pi$ and for $(c_1,c_2)=(5.2,2.3)$ him gives the period $62.8319$ which is almost $20\pi$. I am not able to calculate these two periods and less to calculate the periods corresponding to literal values of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

$(2)$ Another way to look at this problem could be the analisis of the rational function $F(X,Y)$ defined by $$F(X;Y)= \frac{2(2X)}{X^2+1}+\frac{2Y}{Y^2+1}$$ where $X=\tan\left(\dfrac{c_1\omega}{2}\right)$ and $Y=\tan\left(\dfrac{c_2\omega}{2}\right)$.

But this is a simple COMMENT.

Comment: it is not true that $f$ is periodic if $c_1/c_2$ is irrational - when you graph of course you cannot really graph $f$ for irrational $c_1,c_2$ as the graphing software will always use some rational approximation, so of course $f$ appears periodic; in reality $f$ is only quasi periodic in general;

Comment: @Conrad: In face of silence for the difficulty, I wanted just write a comment about it. I don't say it is periodic but it seems it is (motivated for the two periods of Wolfram and you are right but I forgot in that moment the irrational values for the constants)

Comment: In any case the downvote is absolutely clear for me it was motivated by a bad conscience. A comment wanted to help the OP and not more don't deserve a downvote.

Comment: imho one thing this site is useful for is integrity so (trivially) incorrect math should be corrected when pointed out - it happened to me a few times and I always corrected rather than hiding behind ambiguous words like "seems" which is unuseful; so you correct your comment, I change my downvote

Comment: @Conrad: Believe me please: I was "sure" that you were not who downvoted. Anyway, dear friend, I wanted to communicate the following, as a simple information: **for $\sin(\sqrt2x)$ Wolfram gives the period $\sqrt2\pi$ and for $\sin(\sqrt3x)$ Wolfram gives the period $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$. But for $\sin(\sqrt2x)+\sin(\sqrt3x)$ Wolfram does not give period**